# how to detect internal wifi card as physical device instead virtual ethernet device in vmware

Tags: wireless-networking, backtrack

I have installed vmware and using backtrack in it. it does not detect wireless network cards as physical devices instead   wireless card are seen as virtual ethernet devices

so is there any way that i can use internal wireless card as physical device ?

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot. You are not seeing any wireless card at all. What you have is a *virtual* internet adapter which is made to communicate with your host's working interface, be that ethernet or wifi, or3G, or whatever. But from within the VM you cannot control the wifi card any more than you can control the ethernet card.

Yet there is a way around that: if you have a USB wifi adapter, you may get control of that. And if you do, it will look like a true,physical wifi card, which you can use any way you like it, for instance you can put it in   *monitor mode*.

But, I repeat, only with an external wifi card. For use with backtrack (then, why backtrck? why do you not move up to kali linux?) it is expedient to use a high gain wifi USB antenna. Any online store is replete with models satisfying this description; but do make sure, before buying one, that it works with Kali by reading the forum, [here](http://forums.kali.org/forumdisplay.php?1-Kali-Linux-Forums).

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you cannot do anything with that problem.

You should have an external wireless adapter in order to work with wireless networks on the ***virtual box*** or ***VMware workstation***... and again with Bluetooth you should have an external adapter.